# Load database connection data dynamically in Codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, pdo

I'm trying to accomplish the following functionality: I have a main connection to a database (inside application/config/database.php: db['default']), and that connections work, it retrieves data,  I want to use that data to establish a new connection to a different DB.

Is that possible or I need to create an external PDO connection to handle it?

(I'm using Codeigniter 3.1.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of Touheed Khan I was able to reach the solution of my problem, posting it here because I had to do some workaround of the suggested solution to make it work. The following is how my solution is working right now:

**Controller.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller extends CI_Controller {
 public $dynamicDB;

 public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
 }

 public function index() {
  //Somehow retrieve the following information from user.
  $host;
  $user;
  $pass;
  $dbname;
  $port;
  // End of retrieval information from user.

  $this->dynamicDB = array(
   'hostname' => $host,
   'username' => $user,
   'password' => $pass,
   'database' => $dbname,
   'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
   'dbprefix' => '',
   'pconnect' => FALSE,
   'db_debug' => TRUE,
   'port' => $port
  );

  $this->load->model('data_model');
  $result = $this->data_model->select($this->dynamicDB, 
                                      $this->get('id'));
  var_dump($result);
 }
}
```

**Data_model.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Data_model extends CI_Model {
 function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }

 public function returnQuery($query) {
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
   return $query->result();
  } else {
   return array();
  }
 }

 public function select($dynamicDB, $id) {
  $dynamicDB = $this->load->database($dynamicDB, TRUE);

  $dynamicDB->select('*');
  $dynamicDB->where('id', $id);
  $dynamicDB->from('table');

  $query = $dynamicDB->get();
  return $this->returnQuery($query);
 }
}
```

Comment: Nicely implemented buddy... you can move dynamicDB declaration to helper that will give your reusability If you want to use this in any other controller in current application.

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for the tip!! Will do!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add array to /config/database.php

Like this article
http://tutsnare.com/connecting-multiple-database-in-codeigniter/ And also in CodeIgniter Documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases

**Edit**

Maybe you need this post
[codeigniter database configuration programmatically form user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187228/codeigniter-database-configuration-programmatically-form-user-input)

Comment: As exposed on the previous answer, the problem is that I don't have the connection data until I make the second connection. So I can't set the second one beforehand. How do I set the new DB configuration from the inside controller.

Comment: So do you need to keep the original plus the new database. Reading through the Codeigniter Documentation, gives you many options on how to do anything you want...

Answer (score 0):

```html
$this->db2 = $this->load->database('seconddb', TRUE);    // 'seconddb' is a connection array key in database config like 'default'.
```

Refer this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269596/4419992) for more information, repox has explained everything in detail.

If more help needed, I'm happy to help.

Thanx, Happy Coding.

Comment: Ok I get it, but my problem is in how do I pass the new data to the database.php file? Because I have worked with different databases before, but the database.php file does  a autoload before I have the data for the new connection I can't pass the data "on time".

Comment: @Lvkz : 

You can pass whole config array to $this->load->database() function.

Refer this answer for details http://stackoverflow.com/a/25459842/4419992

Comment: Hey @Touheed Khan, your last comment pointed me in the right direction! Will add an answer with the details of my findings.